# Web Access Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I can SSH into my vagrant box fine, and also do this from another computer on the network which is great, but I cant seem to access the URL.

Even on the host computer when I try visiting 192.168.1.127 I get

*This web page is not available*

**Currently my ifconfig on SSH :**

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:91:14:ca
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe91:14ca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:490 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:314 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:52297 (52.2 KB)  TX bytes:43532 (43.5 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:5b:38:98
          inet addr:192.168.1.127  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:762 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:72423 (72.4 KB)  TX bytes:8567 (8.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

**My vagrant file :**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "chef/ubuntu-14.04"

  config.vm.network :public_network, ip: '192.168.1.127', :netmask => '255.255.255.0', :bridge => 'eth0' 

  config.vm.synced_folder "../pqs4", "/var/www/pqs4/", :nfs => false, :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"]

  config.vm.define :pqs4 do |t|
  end

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "pqs4"
    v.memory = 4096
    v.cpus = 4
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision.sh"

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |provisioner|
    provisioner.inventory_path = "hosts"
    provisioner.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    provisioner.verbose = 'v'
    provisioner.limit = 'all'
  end

end
```

Comment: Wait, do you get a timeout or an error page from the webserver?

Comment: In other words, can you please paste the output of `curl -I http://192.168.1.127`?